# How do I return an integer value from VBScript to Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I tried the code below but it does not work:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`CSCRIPT "C:/../myvbs.vbs"`) do set num=%%a

echo %num%
```

In the `myvbs.vbs` code, I am passing the number as follows:

```
wscript.echo number
```

Comment: You missed the apostrophes to enclose the command: `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ('CSCRIPT "C:/../myvbs.vbs"') do set num=%%a`

Comment: I missed it. Thank you. I tried enclosing within apostrophe. It didn't work. for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ('CSCRIPT "C:\..\myvbs.vbs"') do set num=%%a

Comment: I got that. I am supposed to enclose within `` not single quote ''

Comment: In case `usebackq` is provided, enclose the command line within back-ticks; without `usebackq`, use apostrophes...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Are you aware that `C:/../myvbs.vbs` (or `C:\..\myvbs.vbs`) points to `C:\myvbs.vbs`? where is your `myvbs.vbs` script actually located?

Comment: C drive. I have backward slashes in my code. No issues with it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the forward slashes which should be backward slashes, you've stipulated to use back quotes without using them.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`CSCRIPT "C:\..\myvbs.vbs"`) do…
```

Although technically they shouldn't be needed

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('CSCRIPT "C:\..\myvbs.vbs"') do…
```

Comment: @newuser, it certainly helps if your comment is entered below my correct solution/answer, _and any reputation_.

Comment: I used back slashes in my actual code. I posted it wrong here. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Please check my response again… The solution, which I provided you with was using back quotes, as you had opted out of using standard single quotes, _(although also missing in your post)_, with your *usebackq* entry. I fixed the backslashes only because @Aacini didn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**myvbs.vbs**

```
returnIntegerValue = 5
WScript.Quit returnIntegerValue
```

**test.bat**

```
cscript.exe myvbs.vbs
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```